# Touchstart Event delegation

Tags: javascript, jquery

**update: this problem occurs on elements dinamically created**
I have a page where i load products in ajax into a grid. Each product is a div that i want to be clickable to add its information to a cart.

All works fine using Jquery click event but this page must be used on mobile so i want to use touchstart event but how i wrote it doesn't work!

It seems event delegation doesn't work for touchstart or something else.

this is the code, in Chrome or Firefox in Desktop page click works, if i emulate mobile device touch doesn't work, any ideas?

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-3 col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-3 ">
    <div class="tiles" id="products"></div>
</div>

$("#products").on("click touchstart", ".product-tile", function (e) {
    console.log("OK");
});

function getProducts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/aj/ProductWs.asmx/GetListJson",
        data: "{ id_category: '<%= id_category%>' }",
        success: function (data) {
            var j = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
            var products = '';
            var colors = ["bg-blue-madison", "bg-purple-studio", "bg-green-meadow", "bg-grey-cascade", "bg-red-intense", "bg-green", "bg-blue-steel", "bg-yellow-lemon", "bg-red-sunglo"];                        

            if (j != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                    var colore = colori[Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)];
                    products += '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><div class="tiles-bar product-tile tile ' + colore + '" data-idproduct = "' + j[i]["ID_Product"] + '" data-name = "' + j[i]["Name"] + '" data-price = "' + j[i]["Price"] + '"><div class="tile-object"><div class="name">' + j[i]["Name"] + ' € ' + j[i]["Price"] + '</div></div></div></div>';
                }
            }
            $("#product").append(products);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: For mobile device this plugin might help https://github.com/benmajor/jQuery-Touch-Events

Comment: It seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/mzksre7x/

Comment: @Alvaro your code is correct but in my situation i dinamically create divs with jquery after reading products from database

Comment: @GillesC i will try your solution but i would to know the cause of the problem

Comment: Please provide the AJAX call, and how you are dynamically creating elements.

Comment: @DanielShillcock updated code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem: resizing browser window at different resolution I saw that neither click worked, so i looked at computed properties searching what have changed. The property **float** for the elemente under the div "product" under a certain resolution was unset, then i set manually to have float left and magically this problem disappeared. Now i have the problem that touch works two times each touch but this is another story. 
I also followed @Daniel Shillcock promise hint even if was not that the problem. Thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring an `onclick` before the newly created DIV elements have been rendered. Assign the eventlistener *after* the DOM has been updated, as below:

`promise()` documentation https://api.jquery.com/promise/

```
function getProducts() {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "/aj/ProductWs.asmx/GetListJson",
      data: "{ id_category: '<%= id_category%>' }",
      success: function(data) {
        var j = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);

        var products = '';
        var colors = ["bg-blue-madison", "bg-purple-studio", "bg-green-meadow", "bg-grey-cascade", "bg-red-intense", "bg-green", "bg-blue-steel", "bg-yellow-lemon", "bg-red-sunglo"];

        if (j != null) {
          for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
            var colore = colori[Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)];
            products += '<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"><div class="tiles-bar product-tile tile ' + colore + '" data-idproduct = "' + j[i]["ID_Product"] + '" data-name = "' + j[i]["Name"] + '" data-price = "' + j[i]["Price"] + '"><div class="tile-object"><div class="name">' + j[i]["Name"] + ' € ' + j[i]["Price"] + '</div></div></div></div>';
          }
        }
        var $product = $('#product');
        $product.append(products).promise().done(function({
            $product.on("click touchstart", ".product-tile", function(e) {
              console.log("OK");
            });
          })
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: I don't know how this jsfiddle works: https://jsfiddle.net/kfqpb31q/12/ . Even though I'm appending the tag after 5 seconds. Somehow something is wrong. So promise() is not what the solution might be.

Comment: It works because you're circumventing the asynchronous nature of jQuery using `setTimeout():`

Comment: @DanielShillcock are you trying this code in mobile emulation? because my problem is the same, i followed what you do and again, in mobile emulation, touch doesn't work. If i don't use mobile emulation, click works